# changing the position of all childs of a node except the parent

Tags: ios, swift, children, nodechildren

I have a main node and it has 5 childs.
I want to change the position.y of the 5 childs without changing the position.y of the main node.

is there a way to do this?
maybe something like:

```
for children in mainnode.children{
children.position.y = children.position.y - 10
}
```

I know that this isn't right, but maybe something like it.

I have been struggling with it for days now, anybody that can help me out?

EDIT: my question is: how do I edit the children of a node. (the example code I gave above is what I tried but didn't work: it gives error on the seconds line: "@value $T9 is not identical to CGFloat")

Comment: without more context, this should work. I'm assuming you're talking about representations with views(because the coordinates)..

Comment: If you just update the children, the parent isn't affected. You need to clarify your issue.

Comment: but it's giving me an error on the second line of my example code: "@value $T9 is not identical to CGFloat"

Comment: Your question still isn't clear. As @rmaddy said, changing the position of the five children won't change the position of the parent node...

Comment: If you just want to get rid of error, try `children.position.y = children.position.y - CGFloat(10.0)`

Comment: @ sasquatch: didn't fix the error, the 1st "position" and "y" are marked.
@ABakerSmith: In the question I am saying I have 5 children, but in real I have like 50 children which keep getting more and more, all with the same name. So I need a function(I guess a for...in) to update all the position of the children at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need is to update the position of all the children try this:

```
for child in mainnode.children as! [SKNode] {
    // Update the position
}
```

Your error was probably coming from the fact that `children` is of type `[AnyObject]` and so `child` was of type `AnyObject`, not `SKNode`.

Comment: error: braced block of statements is an unused close (1st line)
         use of unresolved identigier "child" (2nd line)

But I guess solving the first line will solve the second line too, but what is the problem?